# Is it possible to inject custom settings into my iOS application "Notifications" settings dialog?

Tags: ios, push-notification, settings

I cannot find any explanation on the internet how to inject my custom subscription settings into the Notifications settings dialog. For example iPhoto has an extra setting "Show Photos Stream Alerts From". Is it some hardcoded stuff from Apple that I cannot do in my App?

Answer (score 3):

The specialized Notifications settings for iPhoto are specific for that app. As you guessed, it's coded by Apple. iPhoto is an included (default) app, and you cannot do the same thing in your own app.

You will have to put your app settings in the Settings app ([settings bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)) or in the app itself.